# How to open Safari with Cordova 3.5 on iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, cordova, safari

I read numerous threads about this problem, but it seems that usual solutions do not work with Cordova 3.5 and iOS 7.1.

So, I'm trying to open an URL in the device default browser, so that the user is able to come back to the app.

This is what I tried:

Does not work:

```
<a onClick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://targetURL.com',{openExternal:true})">Link A </a>
```

Opens the target URL in full screen; the user can not go back to the app:

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://targetURL.com/','_system')">Link B</a>
```

Also tried the `href`&`target='_blank'` approach, with no more success...

Comment: Did you try loading with inAPP browser plugin?

Comment: The second option is the good one, but you have to install inApBrowser plugin and you have an error on the code, you are missing a ' at the endo of the url

Comment: Thanks, Yes I installed the InAppBrowser plugin. It appears well in the Build Phases tab of XCode. Thanks also for the '; I edited the question as this was a typo. So, what do you think am I missing here?

Comment: `<a onclick="window.open('http://example.com/','_system')">External</a>` worked for me as well. And like @jcesarmobile said, you need to have inAppBrowser plugin installed: `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Comment: None of these solutions work for me either, using PhoneGap 3.5. I downloaded the plugin, too. I hope I can figure something out without having to hack the native iOS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it by adding this to the implementation of `MainViewController` in `MainViewController.m`, thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369303/phonegap-cordova-open-external-link-into-safari-instead-of-full-screen-inapp?rq=1).

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *str = url.absoluteString;
    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"http://"];
    NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:@"https://"];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound || range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}
```

}